# Good Evening, why my code doesn't print anything in the console although he has a "system.out.println" instruction?

Tags: java, multithreading

First of all my code try to multiply a 2D array the idea is that i want to calculate each element with new thread and at last i want to measure the time that it will take but when i want to do that for a large size of arrays, the "system.out.println()" instruction doesn't print anything, and here it is my code:

```
////// calcSerial class
package Solutions;

import java.util.Random;

public class CalcSerial {

    public static int[][] initializeMatrixRandom(int row, int col){
        int[][] mat = new int[row][col];
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<row;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
                mat[i][j] = random.nextInt(10);
            }
        }
        return mat; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int row = 4000;
        int column = 4000;

        int[][] A = initializeMatrixRandom(row, column);
        int[][] B = initializeMatrixRandom(column, row);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        OneThreadCalc [][]otc = new OneThreadCalc[A.length][B[0].length];

        int[][] res = new int[A.length][B[0].length];
        for(int i=0;i< A.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<B[0].length;j++) {
                otc[i][j] = new OneThreadCalc(i, j, A, B);
                otc[i][j].start();
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i< A.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<B[0].length;j++) {
                try{
                    otc[i][j].join();
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }

        }
        for(int i=0;i< A.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<B[0].length;j++) {
                res[i][j] = 0;
                res[i][j] = otc[i][j].getElement();
            }
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        long totalTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000000000;


        System.out.println("Program took "+ totalTime + "s.");


}
}


////// And the OneThreadCalc class is : /////////


package Solutions;

public class OneThreadCalc extends Thread{

    int i;
    int j;
    int A[][];
    int B[][];
    int res = 0;
    OneThreadCalc(int i, int j, int A[][], int B[][]){
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;

    }

    public void run() {
        int colA = A[0].length;
        for(int k=0;k<colA;k++) {
            res += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }

    }
    public int getElement() {
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your program finish? Did you debug it? Do you really create 16 million threads or did I get something wrong?

Comment: You can run with 400 rather than 4000 and it almost took 10s for me. Approximately it will take 100 times more than that for 4000. Which means like 1000 seconds, roughly around 16 minutes if it does not overflow or outofmemory

Comment: I think a better option would be to break down the job into parts. First do a set of threads like 100000 then next 100000 and so on.

Comment: No, don't do 100000 threads. Use a threadpool instead.

Comment: Thank you all, it really made a sense.